# Height not stretching in first column of two column nav menu

Tags: css

UPDATE:

Sorry, I shouldve updated my code a bit more before posting. This updated version shows that I need a 1px white border around the blue blocks. And if the "row" is taller because of text overflow, I need the blue block to be "taller" as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/76VRz/53

----- Original question:

I've looked around and mostly the questions about this are for two column pages. I need assistance with a two column nav menu I'm creating. I need the height and background color that goes along with it to stretch whenever the text in column two overflows to next line. I've tried various adjustments and can't seem to get the right one to work.

Can someone please take a look at my jsFiddle and see if you can fix this? I need the left column to be a solid color of blue.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/76VRz/

```
.nav-bar-container { font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px;   }
.nav-bar-row { width:225px;  }
.nav-bar-column-1 { background-color:#4055a1; width:20px;   float:left;}
.nav-bar-column-2 { margin-left:10px; padding-left: 2.5em; text-indent:-1.2em;  }
.nav-bar-column-2 a { color:#4055a1;  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `nav-bar-column-1` for blue background only? What about this http://jsfiddle.net/76VRz/38/ ?

Comment: Thanks dfsq, but eventually I'm going to have a slight white border surrounding these blue blocks. And I also may change the color of blue block upon hover.

Comment: This is also possible without extra markup: http://jsfiddle.net/76VRz/55/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to ave so many divs like that. it would be easier and neater to do it with a

```
<div>
    <p>one line</p>
    <p>one line</p>
    <p>one line</p>
    <p>two lines of text over two lines</p>
</div>
```

here's a demo of your requirements http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/xkN39/1/

Comment: Sorry, I shouldve updated my code a bit more before posting. This updated version shows that I need a 1px white border around the blue blocks. And if the "row" is taller because of text overflow, I need the blue block to be "taller" as well. 

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/76VRz/53/